# How do I organize Ansible's hosts file per role and location?

Tags: ansible

My project is to use Ansible to manage three server clusters each of which live in different cities and states, Boston, Chicago and Los Angeles. So in each data center I have two httpd servers, three tomcat servers and two database servers.

In my /etc/ansible/hosts file I have already set up groups based on the machine's role http, tomcat, and db.

My question is, do I now create a second set of (geographical) groups in /etc/ansible/hosts where the same machines are listed under the data center's name or should this be done in group_vars files? Or should I set up a parent:child groups in /etc/ansible/hosts ?

Comment: I'm looking for best practices, not whether it can be done a specific way. 
Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you will need a way to limit plays to specific datacenters. Therefore it is essential to create groups for the datacenters in the inventory file.

If you have groups for the "role" (http, tomcat and db) and also location (boston, chicago and la) you can target any combination of these machines in your playbooks, e.g. `hosts: boston&db` would limit the play to all hosts contained in both groups boston and db.